# Problems with sending integer values over network using read & write in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking

So I have a sender and a receiver. The writing function of the sender looks like that:

```
void write_ConnectorD_out_dispatch_user(GEN_TYPE_int *sockfd,struct sockaddr_in* addr,GEN_TYPE_char *prefix,GEN_TYPE_int value){
    GEN_TYPE_int n;
    if (connect(*sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) addr, sizeof(*addr)) < 0) {
        printf("Receiver not yet ready \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        GEN_TYPE_char append[256];
        GEN_TYPE_char data[256];
        sprintf(data, "%d", value);
        strcpy(append, prefix);
        strcat(append, data);
        n = write(*sockfd, append, strlen(append));
        if (n < 0) {
            // error("ERROR writing from socket");
        }
    }
```

And the reading function of the receiver looks like that:

```
GEN_TYPE_char *read_ConnectorD_in_dispatch_high(GEN_TYPE_int *sockfd,GEN_TYPE_int *newsockfd,GEN_TYPE_socklen_t *clilen,struct sockaddr_in* cli_addr){
    GEN_TYPE_int n;
    *newsockfd = accept(*sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) cli_addr, clilen);
    GEN_TYPE_char buffer_recv[256];
    bzero(buffer_recv, 256);
    n = read(*newsockfd, buffer_recv, 255);
    if (n < 0) {
        // error("ERROR reading from socket");
    }
    return buffer_recv;
}
```

Using the write function I send the value 12 to the receiver. But the receiver  doestn print the correct value. It prints some random bytes instead. I try to convert the data back to the integer but then i get 0 as the value.
Any idea what I am missing?

cheers

Sergey

Comment: `buffer_recv` is stored on the stack. You can't return that.

Comment: Are you receiving the message via an event handler using a receive event, i.e. somewhere on your system you should have events defined that tell you when data is ready, etc.... TCP_CONNECT   
TCP_DISCONNECT, TCP_DATAREADY.  If not, then you may be attempting to read before there is any message to read.

Comment: In addition to returning a stack-allocated array, you also assume that the `read()` will read exactly the number of bytes written, which is not a safe assumption.  It could read fewer (with the rest being available via one or more subsequent reads).  If the sender followed up with additional writes, then it could also read more.  `read(2)` and `write(2)` have stream semantics, not message semantics.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer_recv` is stored on the stack. You can't return that. –  Wimmel